Snapping in PostGIS topologies
I'm trying to create a topology from a geographic table in PostGIS with the boundaries of adjacent polygons snapped to each other. I prepared the topology with the following commands:
SELECT topology.CreateTopology('mytopology', <srid>)

then
SELECT topology.AddTopoGeometryColumn('mytopology', <source schema>, <source table>, 'topogeom', 'POLYGON')

To create the topogeometry, I used the following command:
UPDATE <source schema>.<source table> SET topogeom=topology.toTopoGeom(geom, 'mytopology', 1, 1)

I expected that setting the tolerance to 1 in the last argument would result in snapping any boundaries between two adjacent polygons that are within 1 unit of each other. However, after checking the results, I discovered that the topology created multiple sliver faces. In cases where there were two edges for one of the sliver faces, running ST_HausdorffDistance() on those two edges results in less than 1.
Am I correct that setting the tolerance is supposed to snap boundaries between adjacent polygons with a Hausdorff distance of less than the tolerance would be snapped to one boundary so that there would be no face between the two polygons?
If so, why would the slivers appear?
If not, is there something else that would work for snapping the adjacent boundaries to each other?

What projection are you using? 1 unit can be quite large in WGS84. If your projection are UTM that would work.

SRID, 2263. 1 unit is 1 ft. Isn't tolerance in the unit of the SRID anyway?
